# Prove that the set of square terms is closed

Tags: real-analysis

If $C$ is a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$, prove that the set $D= \{ x^2 : x\in C$ } is also closed.

My attempt!

Let  $(y_n)_{n>1}$ a convergent sequence with limit $y\in\mathbb{R}$, then for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ exist $x_n \in C$ such that $y_n=x^2_n$. How I prove that $y\in D$?

Comment: What is $A$? Did you mean $C$?

Comment: Edit now!, Thanks

Comment: If $y_n \in D$, then at least one of $\pm \sqrt{y_n}$ is in $C$.

Comment: @copper.hat I've prove before that if $(x_n) \rightarrow x$ then $(x^2_n) \rightarrow x^2$. How can I use this fact for what I need?

Comment: If $y_n \to y$ and $y_n \in D$, then either $\sqrt{y_n} \in C$ an infinite number of times or $-\sqrt{y_n} \in C$ an infinite number of times. What would $\sqrt{y_n}$ of $-\sqrt{y_n}$ converge to? How would that help you?

Comment: @copper.hat 
This leads me to  accumulation points?, I apologize but I do not understand much of the subject why I ask for your help in being more detailed and specific please

Comment: Can you show that at least one of $\pm \sqrt{y} \in C$?

Comment: @copper.hat Ummm, I'm stuck on this, I'm sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the sequence $x_n$ as you have constructed, without loss of generality, assume that an infinite number of terms are of the form $x_n=\sqrt{y_n}$.  Define the subsequence $y_{n_k}$ consisting of all terms for which $x_{n_k}=\sqrt{y_{n_k}}$.

Since $y_{n_k}\to y$ and by continuity of the square root function, $\sqrt{y_{n_k}}\to \sqrt{y}$. That is, $x_{n_k}\to \sqrt{y}$. By closure of $C$ we have $\sqrt{y} \in C$ so $y\in D$.

Answer (score 1):

If $C$ is closed then so is $B= C \cup (-C)$, the set that contains
$C$ and is symmetric about zero.

It is easy to check that $D = \{ x^2 | x \in B\}$ and if $x \in B$ then,
by definition $-x \in B$.

Furthermore, if $x \in B$ then either $x\in C$ or $-x \in C$.

Suppose $y_n \in D$ and $y_n \to y$. Then there is some $x_n \in B$ such that $y_n = x_n^2$ and $x_n \ge 0$.
We have $x_n^2 \to y$ and so $y \ge 0$, so we can take square roots
to get $x_n \to \sqrt{y}$. Hence $\sqrt{y} \in B$ and
so one of $\pm \sqrt{y} \in C$. And so $y \in D$ as required.